# selenium test failure on jenkins server

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run BDD  test case using Jbehave , selenium  it works fine in local environment but fails when i am running through Jenkins. Error i am seeing as below :

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='my-id'] 
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09' 
System info: host: 'lt29nxas000000u.opr.statefarm.org', ip: '10.56.8.88', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_95' Session ID: 10a633701cc1b7e5b678d24c0ee8890e 
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.D1Awd8, chromedriverVersion=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881)}, networkConnectionEnabled=false, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, rotatable=false, setWindowRect=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, version=64.0.3282.186, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=false, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, acceptInsecureCerts=false}]
```

I can see the application logs that traffic generated by BDD execution but it fails to get the element , i tried increasing timeout values but no luck  . I am using Headless Chrome browser on jenkins .

appreciate any help !

Comment: on further research it appears on jenkins  chrome capability   acceptSslCerts=false is making problem , Does any one know how to set it to true ?

Comment: this is Firefox but should apply to you as well: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/420 (not the bug but the shown code)

Answer (score 1):

The error stack trace does gives us some hint on whats wrong happening as follows :

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='my-id'] 
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09' 
System info: host: 'lt29nxas000000u.opr.statefarm.org', ip: '10.56.8.88', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_95' Session ID: 10a633701cc1b7e5b678d24c0ee8890e 
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.D1Awd8, chromedriverVersion=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881)}, networkConnectionEnabled=false, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, rotatable=false, setWindowRect=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, version=64.0.3282.186, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=false, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, acceptInsecureCerts=false}]
```

It is clear from the error stacktrace that the *Driver info* is not recognized as follows :

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- You are using *chrome=64.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.53.1** of **2016-06-30 19:26:09** which is almost **2 years** older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.7.0_95** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v7u95* , *Selenium Client v2.53.1* , *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.35*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v64.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.9.1**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Keep *ChromeDriver* at  ***ChromeDriver v2.35*** level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v64.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes][2])
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Instead of a generic *Locator Strategy* as **By.xpath: //*[@id='my-id']** try to use a more specific [*Locator Strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which will identify the *WebElement* uniquely. An example of an `xpath` :

  ```
  //tagName[@attribute='attribute_value']
  ```
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 1):

`2.53.1` seems like a version inherited in a spring-boot project. Anyway whether you can update it to something more recent or not, you can find below 3 options for some Selenium version where I tried it, but they should all yield the same result with v2.35.528161 of the Chrome Driver which you're using.:

**1)** Selenium 2.53.1:

```java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true); // no dedicated method
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

**Result**

```
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'x.y.z.w', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             v--------v--------v  v-----------v----------v
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73), userDataDir=C:\Users\batman\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir17748_29858}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=64.0.3282.186, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
```

---

**2)** Selenium 3.4.0:

```java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true); // dedicated method
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

**Result**

```
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'x.y.z.w', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             v---------v-------v  v-----------v----------v
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73), userDataDir=C:\Users\batman\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11844_18447}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=64.0.3282.186, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
```

---

**3)** Selenium 3.9.1:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // use "Options" constructor instead of deprecated capabilities one
```

**Result**

```
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'x.y.z.w', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
              v-----------v-----------v  v---------v--------v
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca..., userDataDir: C:\Users\batman\AppDa...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 64.0.3282.186, webStorageEnabled: true}
```

Comment: Tried first option and it seems capability values got updated  - acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true  . But seems problem still persist . some of our page scripts hosted on static content servers not getting loaded .

Comment: @Vin Then perhaps there is some other issue. Try to [do some debugging, dump the page content to log or create a PDF, etc](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#frontend) to see if and what's being loaded.